# Put json data inside table/div

Tags: codeigniter, jquery

Here's my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      url: base_url+'main/activity_window',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(html) {
              //don't know what the code here :(
      }          
    });
},30000);
});
</script>
```

This is the code inside my controller:

```
function activity_window(){
    $this->load->model('core_m');
    $core_m = new Core_m;
    $t = $core_m->get_waybill_created();
    foreach($t as $result){
        echo json_encode(array('name'=>$result['waybillno']));
    }
}
```

This is my div/table:

```
<div id="put_data_here"></div>
<table id="put_data_here"></table>
```

This is the result from the controller:

{"name":"MAIN-0056-00000006"}{"name":"MAIN-0056-00000005"}{"name":"MAIN-0056-00000004"}{"name":"MAIN-0056-00000003"}{"name":"MAIN-0056-00000002"}{"name":"MAIN-0056-00000001"}

how to put the data inside the div or table like this:

```
New Waybill Entry MAIN-0056-00000006
New Waybill Entry MAIN-0056-00000005
New Waybill Entry MAIN-0056-00000004
New Waybill Entry MAIN-0056-00000003
New Waybill Entry MAIN-0056-00000002
New Waybill Entry MAIN-0056-00000001
```

help me please.. thank you in advance sir..

Answer (score 0):

Why not use jQuery ?

```
function load_page (option) {

     $('#put_data_here').load('something.php?option='+option).fadeIn(300);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In ur success function :

```
  success: function(html) {
          //don't know what the code here :(
          $("#put_data_here").html(html); //If you have jquery added
          document.getElementById("put_data_here").innerHTML = html; // Javascript solution
  }
```

If you want to loop through the json array, then you should do that before adding to html.

Comment: yeah but it will display like this: {"name":"MAIN-0056-00000006"}{"name":"MAIN-0056-00000005"}{"name":"MAIN-0056-000‌​00004"}{"name":"MAIN-0056-00000003"}{"name":"MAIN-0056-00000002"}{"name":"MAIN-00‌​56-00000001"} what i want to do is, it will display something like this: New Waybill Entry MAIN-0056-00000006<br/> New Waybill Entry MAIN-0056-00000005